# java.io.IOException: Permission denied SBT

Tags: java, sbt, java-io, filenotfoundexception

I am having this permission denied problem while i am trying to run my SBT project and also while trying to import project in IntelliJ Idea.As far as i can understand there is problem with permission of my SBT and i tried to find a proper solution but really confused as i am very new in using SBT. If anyone can help me will be really grateful. Thanks

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/mahmud/.sbt/0.13/staging/dafca757a464c53dfda9/projectjava.io.IOException: Permission denied
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
at scala.reflect.io.AbstractFile.fileOrSubdirectoryNamed(AbstractFile.scala:235)
at scala.reflect.io.AbstractFile.fileNamed(AbstractFile.scala:246)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BytecodeWriters$class.getFile(BytecodeWriters.scala:34)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BytecodeWriters$class.scala$tools$nsc$backend$jvm$BytecodeWriters$$getFile(BytecodeWriters.scala:37)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BytecodeWriters$ClassBytecodeWriter$class.writeClass(BytecodeWriters.scala:89)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$AsmPhase$$anon$4.writeClass(GenASM.scala:67)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$JBuilder.writeIfNotTooBig(GenASM.scala:459)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$JMirrorBuilder.genMirrorClass(GenASM.scala:2980)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$AsmPhase.run(GenASM.scala:114)
at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anonfun$compile$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(Eval.scala:177)
at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anonfun$compile$1$1.apply(Eval.scala:177)
at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anonfun$compile$1$1.apply(Eval.scala:177)
at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.atPhase(SymbolTable.scala:207)
at sbt.compiler.Eval.compile$1(Eval.scala:177)
at sbt.compiler.Eval.compileAndLoad(Eval.scala:182)
at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalCommon(Eval.scala:152)
at sbt.compiler.Eval.eval(Eval.scala:96)
at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateDslEntry(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:177)
at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$9.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:117)
at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$9.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:115)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateSbtFile(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:115)
at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:775)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:781)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:780)
at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:58)
at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:780)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadFiles$1$2.apply(Load.scala:788)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadFiles$1$2.apply(Load.scala:788)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at sbt.Load$.loadFiles$1(Load.scala:788)
at sbt.Load$.discoverProjects(Load.scala:799)
at sbt.Load$.discover$1(Load.scala:585)
at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadTransitive(Load.scala:633)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadUnit$1.sbt$Load$$anonfun$$loadProjects$1(Load.scala:482)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadUnit$1$$anonfun$40.apply(Load.scala:485)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadUnit$1$$anonfun$40.apply(Load.scala:485)
at sbt.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1025)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadUnit$1.apply(Load.scala:485)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadUnit$1.apply(Load.scala:459)
at sbt.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1025)
at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:459)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$25$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Load.scala:311)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$25$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Load.scala:310)
at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:91)
at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:90)
at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:140)
at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:365)
at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:320)
at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:316)
at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:305)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$4.apply(Load.scala:146)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$4.apply(Load.scala:146)
at sbt.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1025)
at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:146)
at sbt.Load$.buildPluginDefinition(Load.scala:886)
at sbt.Load$.buildPlugins(Load.scala:852)
at sbt.Load$.plugins(Load.scala:840)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadUnit$1$$anonfun$34.apply(Load.scala:465)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadUnit$1$$anonfun$34.apply(Load.scala:465)
at sbt.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1025)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadUnit$1.apply(Load.scala:464)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadUnit$1.apply(Load.scala:459)
at sbt.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1025)
at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:459)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$25$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Load.scala:311)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$25$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Load.scala:310)
at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:91)
at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:90)
at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:140)
at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:365)
at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:320)
at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:316)
at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:305)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$4.apply(Load.scala:146)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$4.apply(Load.scala:146)
at sbt.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1025)
at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:146)
at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:39)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:496)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:496)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:488)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:488)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:59)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:59)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:93)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:96)
at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:89)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:68)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:63)
at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:63)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:46)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:30)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:22)
at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:57)
at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)[error] java.io.IOException: Permission denied[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Answer (score 0):

That is most definitely an permission issue. You certainly run Intellij as an user who may not access.

> /home/mahmud/.sbt/0.13/staging/dafca757a464c53dfda9/project

Check your user roles.